# Android Jetpack Navigation component issue with splash fragment as root destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Suppose we have 3 fragments with toolbars with up button functionality

```
SplashFragment -> FragmentA -> FragmentB
```

This is the expected flow of app. On reaching FragmentB when user presses back button he should go to FragmentA and again on pressing back button the app should exit.
How can we achieve this behaviour using navigation component?
I have tried to do this using the `app:popUpTo` inside the `action` tag, somehow I managed to make it work for hardware back button but the behaviour for up button didn't change.

Need help on this.

Comment: have you got any solution??

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: this is deprecated on Navigation alpha08，And the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189835/navigation-architecture-component-splash-screen/53648773#53648773) is the current solution.**

This may be the answer you want.
Use `app:clearTask="true"`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
    android:name="xxx.SplashFragment"
    android:label="fragment_splash"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/anim_right_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/anim_left_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/anim_left_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim_right_out"
        app:clearTask="true"/>
```

[Navigation Architecture Component - Splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189835/navigation-architecture-component-splash-screen/53648773#53648773)

Comment: But still, the current root fragment has the back button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.
`fragmentA->fragmentB->fragmentc`
on back, button pressed from FragmentC to FragmentB and then again back pressed and you want to exit the form app. add this line to FragmentA action.

```
app:launchSingleTop="true"
app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it this way:

After App launches Fragment-A clear the backstack i.e.; SplashFragment , Now when the user navigates forward everything is same but after returning to Fragment-A , if he hits back button The app exits .

Hope this helps!

Comment: No thats not gonna work. Here we are talking about navigation component not a normal fragment transaction, I need to update the control flow of navigation but don't know how.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that ,you need to clear your backstack programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar flow in place, what works and I believe is a clean solution is to have your `FragmentA` as the start point of your navigation graph (that will always put in top of the backstack on lunch) then you want to navigate (maybe conditionally) to the `SplashFragment` on the `onStart` (or earlier in the lifecycle) of your `FragmentA`, and finally when you would like your SplashFragment to go away, you use`findNavController().popBackStack()` to pop the fragment. then only Fragment A and B will remain on your stack and back will work as expected.

hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. I am trying to achieve something similar.